# cannot archive app xcode 4,codesign error

Tags: xcode4, archive

i recently uploaded my app to app store now i want to upload a new version of it.i upgraded to xcode 4, re downloaded  all the my developer and distribution certificate,and tried to archive the app for upload but it wont get archived giveing me codesign error

```
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 5.0'
```

so i just deleted everything from my keychain access,xcode organizer and reinstalled everything from provisioning portal
also it when i install the app to my iPad it installs but throws following warning

```
Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
```

i checked all the links on StackOverflow but no luck

Comment: I got this error on 10.7.1, but it disappeared after updating to 10.7.2 and recreating the certificates.

Answer (score 2):

If you view the 'Build settings' of your project, and search for 'Code Signing Identity', ensure you have your Distribution provisioning profile selected for the 'Release' option.

Your Distribution provisioning profile is the one you get from:

iOS provisioning portal -> Provisioning -> Distribution.

Comment: while code signing i had duplicated Code Signing Identity "Release" and renamed it to Distribution(suggested on apple website),and used selected my dist certificate for it
so do i still need to do it for Release too?

Comment: Odd, even though I was building a different configuration ("Ad Hoc") it seemed like it still needed the "Release" one to be set to get rid of the problem. Thanks!